# Is there a way to receive notifications about chat?

Tags: support

The StackExchange navbar provides notifications about comments, answers, and other stuff.  However, I frequently forget about chatrooms I am in. Is there any way to receive updates or notifications from chat rooms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've been in a chat room in the last 2 weeks, people can ping you by name

> @indigochild Hello!

Those show up in your network-wide message box

[image]

Note that SE and SO run different chat servers

Those are the only chat notices I know of.